# Purpose of "useBuiltIns" config in "babel-preset-react"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I understand the usage of "useBuiltIns" config in "[babel-preset-env](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#usebuiltins)".

But I don't quite understand the usage of "useBuiltIns" config in "[babel-preset-react](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react#usebuiltins)".

It says on the documentation:

> boolean, defaults to false. "Will use the native built-in instead of
> trying to polyfill behavior for any plugins that require one."

Not sure what exactly it means.